# How to properly alias a /usr/include header file for inclusion as <foo.h>?

Tags: c++, c++11, alias

Suppose I've written a header named `foo.h`, and that `foo.h` is also the name of one of the headers under `/usr/include`. Now, in my source files, I want to say `#include <foo.h>`, but arrange my build so that the compiler will search the directory with my `foo.h` *before* `/usr/include`. *Note: I realize this is a bad idea in code intended for public/general use; this is intended for a specific use-case where I need to trick source files into including something other than the standard library header for certain testing purposes.*

It is important that users be able to write `#include <foo.h>` exactly, and not, say `#include "foo.h"` or `#include "/path/to/foo.h"` etc. Also, I do want other includes of files in `/usr/include` to work as usual (as much as possible; if they themselves include `foo.h` then I don't care about them).

How do I arrange this in the C or C++ compiler command-line (e.g. with GCC, clang)?

Comment: Requiring that users can write `#include <foo.h>` for a user-defined header is a bad idea e.g. prevent including system-installed headers if a user-defined one is present unless a full file path is specified - which locks developers into a specific configurations.  The usual way (based on what the STANDARD specifies) is that `#include "foo.h"` and `<foo.h>` resolve to user-defined locations and system-defined locations respectively.  That said, it is possible to control directories searched by gcc and clang (either form of `#include`) using command line options or environment variables

Comment: You can specify multiple `-I` options on the command line, in which case the directories are searched in left-to-right order. More https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Comment: @Peter: It's for a very specific use case, I'll clarify that.

Comment: On very specific case with GCC you need to use -iquote, -isystem, -idirafter, -isysroot and/or -nostdinc options to tune the search paths.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: Can you make that into an answer, and suggest what combination of these would be appropriate? Also, I do want other standard library header includes to work as usual.

Comment: @einpoklum No. As mocking/faking only a subset of standard library headers takes very throughout knowledge of particular standard library implementation (and it will potentially break with next update).

Comment: @ÖöTiib: Would it help if I said it was `printf.h`?

Comment: `printf.h` is not typically a system-supplied header.

Comment: @Peter: Well... it's part of glibc, and its in the system include directory... but ok, I suppose we can split hairs a bit. Amended the title.

Comment: This is an implementation detail, and will vary from compiler to compiler.  Clang probably mimics GCC, but CL.EXE will be very different.  You'll want to insert your intercept file location before the system path location.  And if you need to chain to the real header, that will vary by compiler too (e.q., `#include_next <foo.h>`)